# Mouse inside and outside circle event java

Tags: java

So I have this assignment but I have yet to display a message when the mouse pointer is inside of the circle and outside of it. Here is the question from my textbook.

( Geometry: inside a circle? ) Write a program that draws a fixed circle centered at (  100  ,   60  ) with radius 50.Whenever the mouse is moved, display a message indicating whether the mouse point is inside the circle at the mouse point or outside of it, as shown in Figure 15.27a

Here is my code so far: I am not getting any "inside circle" or "outside circle" message and the radius is not 50. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.*;



public class GeometryInsideACircle extends JFrame {

    private CirclePanel canvas = new CirclePanel();

    public GeometryInsideACircle() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //JLabel label = new JLabel();
        //add(label);
        this.add(canvas , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //addMouseListener(this);
        //this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        }

    public class MouseInfo extends JPanel {
        //This is utilized to obtain the circle class because circle would have width = to its height
        Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 60, 50, 50);//circle centered at (100, 60) radius 50

        Point p = new Point();//this will get the location of x and y

        private boolean isInCircle = false;//set to false until pointer enters the circle
        //this constructor will obtain all mouse and circle info utilizing MouseMotionListener and MouseMotionAdapter 
        public MouseInfo() {

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                    if(circle.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        isInCircle = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        isInCircle = false;
                    }

                    p = e.getPoint();//this should obtain the x and y coordinates based upon mouse activity
                    repaint();//this will repaint the pointers locations
                }
            });
        }
        //this will create/draw a circle
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.draw(circle);

            if(isInCircle) {//this should let the user know if mouse pointer is in the circle based upon x and y coordinates
                g.drawString("The mouse point is in the circle" + (int)p.getX() +"," + (int)p.getY(), (int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY() );
            }
            else {//this should let the user know if the mouse pointer is outside of the circle based upon x and y coordinates
                g.drawString("The mouse point is outside of the circle" + (int)p.getX() +"," + (int)p.getY(), (int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY() );
            }
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GeometryInsideACircle frame = new GeometryInsideACircle();
        frame.setTitle("Exercise 16_19");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the simple change

```
public GeometryInsideACircle() {
    JPanel panel = new MouseInfo();
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

It works as advertised.  And if you read the docs for [Ellipse2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html#Ellipse2D.Double%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) You will find that you state the witdh and height; not the radius.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and you're correct about needing to state the width and height of a circle and not the radius. For some reason I believed that the radius needed to be stated. Will re-read again. Program works fine. Again, I am much obliged for your assistance.

Comment: @Murk The standard procedure here at SO is to close a solved question by using the check mark next to the answer.